# How to restore to the previous state in RecyclerView after loading more data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, bundle

I have been working with RecyclerView for a while. I am following lazy loading, so I am showing 10 data on the view each time. If user scroll to the bottom, the page re-load from the TOP! however, I want to stay where it was previously! So, I have tried to use

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```

However, this breaks the UI flow!
My second try is using **onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state);** However, that does not work! My page is re-loads to the top!

```
Parcelable state = layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
```

I have tried every other methods, apparently none is working for me!
Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note : Make sure that you are not initialising or calling setAdapter() method each time after updating your dataset. If not, then**

You have to update your data list and call notifyDataSetChanged() which will update your adapter from existing position.

Let's say you have stored your data into ArrayList mData;

Your getItemCount() would be

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

if (mData != null && mData.length() > 0)
    return mData.size();

    return 0;
}
```

Now create one more method in your adapter which you will called each time whenever you will get new data from server. This method will simply override your dataset and will update your adapter

```
private void updateDataSet(ArrayList<String> mData){

  this.mData = mData;
  notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jai, but it's not working! The page keeps taking me to the top of the list when new data has been added to the screen.

Comment: @ibtehaz : Could you post your adapter?

Comment: @ibtehaz : Your page is getting start from top or you are able to see the same items repeatedly while scrolling?

Comment: @ibtehaz : And also make sure that you are not initialising or calling setAdapter() method each time after updating your dataset

Comment: We were re-initializing the adapter on every spin. Thanks for the help dude :) (y)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this functionality before 2 days ago

I share my idea with you

Make

```
Listview lv; //Assume Find view by Id 
List<Model> models = new ArrayList();
```

Now Make an Adapter and assign blank models

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomeAdapter(context,models);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now when you have new data to load with lazylodaing

do this

```
models.addAll(newModels); //new ModelList
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thats it.

Comment: Thanks @MohitTrivedi

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour Recycler View to recycle/resuse views. As in official docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

 If you are having any view related issues then save your view state in your `List<Object>` like setting visible item or not per position. And in your  `onBindViewHolder` method as per position show/hide your view.